# Unit testing - Parsing a yaml config file with file_get_contents and symfony yaml parser

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, file-get-contents

I want to load the content of a yaml config file. Using Symfony Yaml parser, and according to [their documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html#reading-yaml-files), I have a `parse()` method working like this:

```
    public function parse($filePath)
    {
        $fileAsString = file_get_contents($filePath);

        if (false === $fileAsString) {
            throw new \Exception('Failed to get content of config file.');
        }

        return $this->parser->parse($fileAsString);
    }
```

When testing this method with a virtual file system [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) I noticed that `file_get_contents()` does not only returns false in case of failure but also throws what looks like an error:

```
    public function parse_throws_Exception_for_invalid_filePath()
    {
        // Setup a root directory
        $root = vfsStream::setup();

        // Set a path of a non existing file
        $filePath = $root->url() . '/file';

        // Create a config mock
        $configMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Microblog\Config')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(null)
            ->getMock();

        $configMock->parse($filePath);
    }
```

I also noticed that to be more solid, the `parse` method needed also to take into account the case of an invalide yaml file, which got me to this change in the `parse` method:

```
    public function parse($filePath)
    {
        try {
            return $this->parser->parse(file_get_contents($filePath));
        } 

        catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Catch exception from file_get_contents and yaml parser
            throw new \Exception('Failed to get config file ("'. $e->getMessage() . '").');
        }

        catch (Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException $e) {
            // Catch exception from file_get_contents and yaml parser
            throw new \Exception('Failed to parse config file ("'. $e->getMessage() . '").');
        }
    }
```

But this does not seem to catch any of the exceptions... :(

I've also read that a good alternative to `file_get_contents()` is `cURL` but the config file being a file on the same filesystem, `cURL` does not really seem to be what I need. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if the file exist before the file_get_contents method